# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement threading (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for threading

Tags: python, pip, python-multithreading

I get the error when I try to open this Python

> Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (1.26.15) ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement threading (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for threading  __    ____  ____  ____  ___

I tried to google it, I also tried to install it via `pip`.

Comment: `threading` is a standard, built-in module.  It does not need to be (and in fact, CANNOT be) installed with `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter mentioned, `threading` is indeed a [**built-in** module](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html) in Python.

It is like `pip install os` - just don't do. Instead, `import os` will be the recommended usage.

### Do:

```
from threading import ... # whatever you need
```

### Don't Do:

```
pip install threading
```